# How to bind TextBox Text using TemplateBinding in ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have made a `ControlTemplate` for my user input form like so:

[image]

And here is the xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="formRow" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <StackPanel Margin="0 0 0 16">
                <TextBlock 
                    DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                           Margin="0 0 0 0"
                           FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBox Margin="0 8 0 0" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

What I want to do is to have the text box populated with my view model. As you can see from my `TextBox` definition in the `ControlTemplate`, I have a `TemplateBinding` bind to the property `Text`

However, when I tried using the `ControlTemplate` in my `ContentControl`, binding the `Text` property to a random string, I get a parser error, saying:

`The member "Text" is not recognized or is not accessible`

I tried `TemplateBinding` to content, but as you can see, the property `Content` is already been used to populate my `TextBlock`

How do I bind my `ContentControl`'s text to my `TextBox`'s text?

Here is the partial xaml for `ContentControl`

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <StackPanel>
                <ComboBox Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <ContentControl x:Name="FITextBox" Content="FI Number: " Template="{StaticResource formRow}" Text="asdasd"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `{TemplateBinding Text}` means to bind to a Text property of the templated control, i.e. a ContentControl here. Such a property does not exist. Use a regular Binding instead, like `{Binding Text}`. Or better, derive a custom control from ContentControl that exposes a bindable Text property. Besides that, it seems also wrong that your ControlTemplate does not have a TemplateBinding to the Content property.

Comment: So instead of using a `ContentControl`, I create a `CustomeControl` where I can expose the property `Text` and bind that to the `ControlTemplate`? do you know where can I find a code example? thanks!

Comment: Why do you think ContentControl has a Text property? You can convert the ControlTemplate to a DataTemplate and set it to the `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` property. Then bind your `TextBox` to the `Content ` property. Alternaively, create a UserControl or a custom Control and give it a `Text` property. The `Text` property should be implemented as dependency property.

Comment: `DockPanel.Dock` only takes effect if the parent panel is a DockPanel. It does not affect other panels like the StackPanel.